# My phone Oppo A5 2020 don't have fastboot mode. How to unoock bootloader. I have to root my phone. Can I root my phone without unlocking bootloader?

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, 9.0-pie, oppo-coloros

Oppo A5 2020
Model No is CPH1933
Android Version is 9.0 Pie
Colour Os 6
There is no fastboot hut I got recovery mode only. 
I have to root my phone.
Can I root without unlocking bootloader?
             Or 
Can I unlock bootloader without fastboot mode?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to get to fastboot though adb with `adb reboot bootloader`. I also found a great step by step tutorial [here](https://gearallnews.com/how-to-unlock-the-bootloader-of-oppo-a5guide/#How_to_unlock_the_bootloader_of_Oppo_A5). also in step 8 of that guide it says to boot into fastboot mode, I believe they meant recovery mode. as far as rooting without unlocking the bootloader, it is possible, but not recommendable. i have from experience soft and in one case hard bricked a few devices by doing so. I would suggest getting the bootloader unlocked, flashing a custom recovery, and then falshing a root package along with supersu or magisk. another way you can get root and many other features is by flashing a custom rom, which is essentially installing a differnt custom version of android, you typicall have to enable root acess through the settings and install supersu or magisk.

Comment: When you do `adb reboot bootloader` on that phone, it doesn't go to the bootloader, it says fastboot initially, then it goes to the regular system.   If you do power-voldown    it doesn't go to the bootloader, it goes to a recovery thing called ColorOS